# Download Option in C# code

Tags: c#

I want to show download pop up for .mdb files in my application.i tried using this code:

```
string path = " D:\New people metrix 7th april\People Metrix New Web\Bin\Inbox.mdb";

HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path));
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(path);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

but i get this Error:
Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.
This bug is really killing me !!!...please help me out .

---

**I got it right guys...i had placed imagebutton in update panel so it was not allowing to download..Thanks so much guys for helping me out..**

Answer (score 3):

Well, at the minimum - calling `Response.Clear()` *after* setting your headers looks like a mistake - try moving that to the start?

Answer (score 2):

sFilePath="download/query.txt";
sFileName="query.txt"

HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";
//Because of this 2 line you get pop up 
        ***String Header = "Attachment; Filename=" + sFileName;
      HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", Header);***

```
  System.IO.FileInfo Dfile = new System.IO.FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(sFilePath));
       HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(Dfile.FullName);
     HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this:

```
        string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/" + document.Path + "/" + document.Filename);
        System.IO.FileInfo targetFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);
        if(targetFile.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + targetFile.Name);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", targetFile.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.WriteFile(targetFile.FullName);
        }
```

the document object used is a container of mine with a path and and a filename.

Try it out and let me know if it works, works for me.

Comment: I tried your code...i dint get any errors and also it didnt show browser download...

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this I prefer BinaryWrite to WriteFile, Also I dont set the content length since it will throw in some browsers if you are trying to download a 0 byte file.

```
string path = @"D:\New people metrix 7th april\People Metrix New Web\Bin\Inbox.mdb";
FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(path);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Concat("attachment; filename=", path));
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(fileinfo,.FullName));
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path doesn't escape the '\' characters. When you're calling **Path.GetFileName** it's likely throwing an exception which is caught and either ignored/translated elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Response.Clear(), seems to be the problem here.

You may try this out.

```
public static void ForcedDownload(HttpResponse response, byte[] buffer, string fileName) {
      response.Clear();
      response.Buffer=true;
      response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format(@"attachment;filename={0}", fileName));
      response.Charset="";
      response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
      response.ContentType="application/octet-stream";
      response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
      response.Flush();
      response.End();
    }
```